# Run AngularJS resource tests without mocking responses

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-resource, karma-mocha

I'm using karma, mocha and chai to write tests for the resources in my AngularJS project and everything works great. Today, I'm using `$httpBackend` to mock every response when the resources are doing http requests. I wonder, however, if I would be able to run the tests without mocking the responses and testing out the real backend integration. Can't seem to find any way to do this.

Comment: What's the problem? If you don't use angular-mock or define a mock response it should make an http request. Of course you need to define an absolute URL instead of a relative one and the server has to support CORS and set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the header.

Comment: Unit testing in Angular does not allow any remote call and that is by design. As soon as you inject the mock module from angular mock it replace the default http You can use E2E testing if pages are involved.

Comment: @Chandermani ok.. cool. So there is now way of calling the backend through the angular test framework then. Thanks. If you submit that as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @materik So how can I do E2E testing?  Is there really no way of testing a Web API call?