# Testing $resource without mock

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, typescript, jasmine, angular-resource

I'm trying to test the asynchronous $resource service by Angular. Firstly note that I don't want to mock $resource, I actually want to get the results and test them.

So basically my getCountries method just uses Angular's $resource to return an array of countries.

**Method**

```
getCountries(): any {
        var countries = this.$resource(
            this.apiEndpoint.baseUrl,
            {
                'get': {
                    method: 'GET', isArray: false
                }
            });
        return countries;
}
```

In my spec I'm having trouble with where to run Jasmine's done() method. Please read comments in the code.

**Spec**

```
describe(module', (): void => {
    var one;
    var SelfRegistrationResourceBuilder;

    beforeEach((): void => {
        angular.mock.module(
            'BuilderModule',
            'ngResource'
        );

        inject(
            ['Builder', (_SelfRegistrationResourceBuilder _: ISelfRegistrationResourceBuilder ): void => {
                SelfRegistrationResourceBuilder = _SelfRegistrationResourceBuilder_;
            }]);
    });


    describe('getCountries', (): void => {

        beforeEach((done) => { //done is a parameter in beforeEach
            SelfRegistrationResourceBuilder.getCountries().get(
                (value: any) => {
                    console.log("no error");
                    one = "aValue";
                    done();  //Do I have to call done() here
                }, (error: any) => {
                    console.log("error");
                    one = "aValue";
                    //done();  What about here
                })
            //done();  ..or here
        });

        it("should...", (done) => {
            expect(one).toBe("aValue");
            //done();  and here?
        });
    });
});
```

So my problem seems to be that when I run my code I either get the error stated in the title of this problem or if I play around with which done() methods I call then my variable named "one" is undefined, thus implying that the success and error call backs never got called. I can also prove that the success and error callbacks never get called because their console.log()s don't ever print to the console.

Lastly, **when I check the network section of the developer tools in my browser I don't see any requests to the server.**  Could someone please try to help me out here, I think I have most of it figured out except the calling of done().

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`done` is for async tests. If you test is not async don't use `done` e.g.:

```
    // No done needed
    it("should...", () => {
        expect(one).toBe("aValue");
    });
```

For async tests call it *after the async operation is complete*. So :

```
    beforeEach((done) => { //done is a parameter in beforeEach
        SelfRegistrationResourceBuilder.getCountries().get(
            (value: any) => {
                console.log("no error");
                one = "aValue";
                done();  //  Yes call done
            }, (error: any) => {
                console.log("error");
                one = "aValue";
                // do not call done. You most likely want to throw to show this is an error case. 
            })
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your help but doing that still gives me the same error and my "one" variable is still undefined

Comment: but this is all occurring because my callbacks never get called

Comment: reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346214/run-angularjs-resource-tests-without-mocking-responses) tells me that this might be impossible to do